# Подпапки в Qt-проекте

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Столкнулся с необходимостью разнести файлы проекта по отдельным папкам/группам. К примеру, отдельно папка для гуек, отдельно для бизнес-логики и т.д. Уверен, что это можно сделать, но в упор не вижу, куда тыкать в `QtCreator'е`. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Тебе непонятно как создать qrc файл или создать структуру директорий в этом файле?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если речь идёт о внутренних ресурсах приложения, хранящихся а .qrc, то просто создай подпапки в директории проекта, перекинь туда файлы и заново добавь через "ПКМ"->"Выбрать существующие файлы" по файлу qrc

Comment: Спасибо. А я и не туда совсем...